# Google Drive "get_error not implemented" error

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-drive-api

I'm trying to implement the use of Google Drive in my app but I seem to be getting the following error `"Method 'get_Error' in type 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data.FileList' from assembly 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2, Version=1.2.4647.29713, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation"`. Does anyone know as to why this is occurring? I based my code on the example that Google provides for its tasks API.

Code below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Util;
using System.Diagnostics;
using DotNetOpenAuth.Messaging;
using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using Google.Apis.Util;
using PrepHub.PrepHub;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Threading;
using Google.Apis;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;
using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;
using Google.Apis.Drive;


namespace DriveExample
{
    public partial class GDrive : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private static DriveService _service; // We don't need individual service instances for each client.
        private OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient> _authenticator;
        private IAuthorizationState _state;

        private IAuthorizationState AuthState
        {
            get
            {
                return _state ?? HttpContext.Current.Session["AUTH_STATE"] as IAuthorizationState;
            }
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (_service == null)
            {
                _service = new DriveService(_authenticator = CreateAuthenticator());
            }


            if (HttpContext.Current.Request["code"] != null)
            {
                _authenticator = CreateAuthenticator();
                _authenticator.LoadAccessToken();
            }

            var ni = _service.Files.List().Fetch();

       }


        private OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient> CreateAuthenticator()
        {

            var provider = new WebServerClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description);
            provider.ClientIdentifier = ClientCredentials.ClientID;
            provider.ClientSecret = ClientCredentials.ClientSecret;
            var authenticator =
                new OAuth2Authenticator<WebServerClient>(provider, GetAuthorization) { NoCaching = true };
            return authenticator;
        }

        private IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(WebServerClient client)
        {
            // If this user is already authenticated, then just return the auth state.
            IAuthorizationState state = AuthState;
            if (state != null)
            {
                return state;
            }
            // Check if an authorization request already is in progress.
            state = client.ProcessUserAuthorization(new HttpRequestInfo(HttpContext.Current.Request));
            if (state != null && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.AccessToken) || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(state.RefreshToken)))
            {
                // Store and return the credentials.
                HttpContext.Current.Session["AUTH_STATE"] = _state = state;
                return state;
            }

            string scope = DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue();
            OutgoingWebResponse response = client.PrepareRequestUserAuthorization(new[] { scope });
            response.Send(); 
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing some of your assemblies are out of date.  That error will occur when you have an assembly for example, lets say foo.dll (v1) and that assembly is being referenced by bar.dll (v2).  A class in bar.dll is expecting something in to be present on a class in Foo and its not there.  In your case, its the get accessor for a property called `Error` on the class `FileList`.  Double check all your assemblies to make sure they are all at their most recent version (s).

Comment: I had the exact same problem with using the "Google.Apis.Calendar.v3." api....i grabbed the source file for the api (calendar) and Turns out that google didnt  "implement interface member 'Google.Apis.Requests.IDirectResponseSchema.Error'" in like 11 places in their api. so i went ahead  and implemented it. sorted things out. il try the same with drive later. but calendar seems to be working now. Thanks for responding though! Cheers.